# Authy PHP - You are not passing the user params correctly

Tags: php, curl, authy

I'm using the Authy PHP wrapper (authy-php) but when I come to creating a new user I get

> You are not passing the user params correctly

```
require("./vendor/autoload.php");
$authy_api = new Authy\AuthyApi('My API Key here');
$user = $authy_api->registerUser('g.******@*****.co.uk', '7***-9**-9**', '44');
if($user->ok()){
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($user);
    print "</pre>";
}else{
   foreach($user->errors() as $field => $message) {
      printf("$field = $message");
   }
}
```

Comment: Try making '44' just 44

Comment: Already did but get the same error. The only other change I did was to add "'verify'        => false" to the GuzzleHTTP options as I'm running from localhost for now.

Comment: Is your phone number in the correct format?

Comment: Tried with/without leading zero. Tried with/without dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, in an attempt to stop localhost SSL screwing up my script, I stoppepd the ip resolve. But putting it back it worked.

I feel very stupid.

To those testing Authy on localhost, just stick verify = false on the defaults for Guzzle HTTP on AuthyApi.php.